# How to convert a list with splitted strings to a possible value sets?

Tags: c#, list

I need to implement a module which will convert a List which with splitted string values to a possible value sets.

For Example

consider the list contains following values

```
1
1,2
3
4
5
```

The module should convert the above list to list of possible value sets

```
1,2,3,4,5
1,1,3,4,5
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rawling's answer is pretty solid, but i don't find it easy to read and understand.  Here's another way, using less Linq.

```
    private List<string> Process(IEnumerable<string> input)
    {
        List<string> data = new List<string>();
        int preExpandCount = 0, offset = 0;
        foreach (string inputItem in input)
        {
            List<string> splitItems = inputItem.Split(',').ToList();
            if (data.Count > 0)
                preExpandCount = ExpandList(data, splitItems.Count - 1);

            offset = 0;
            foreach (string splitItem in splitItems)
            {
                if (preExpandCount == 0)
                    data.Add(splitItem);
                else
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < preExpandCount; i++)
                        data[i + offset] = String.Format("{0},{1}", data[i + offset], splitItem);
                    offset += preExpandCount;
                }
            }
        }

        return data.OrderBy(e => e).ToList();
    }

    private int ExpandList(List<string> existing, int count)
    {
        int existingCount = existing.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            existing.AddRange(existing.Take(existingCount).ToList());
        return existingCount;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This will do it, although it will return your example in the opposite order:

```
static IEnumerable<string> Permutations(
    IEnumerable<string> input,
    char separator)
{
    var sepAsString = separator.ToString();

    var enumerators = input
       .Select(s => s.Split(separator).GetEnumerator())
        .ToArray();
    if (!enumerators.All(e => e.MoveNext())) yield break;

    while (true)
    {
        yield return String.Join(sepAsString, enumerators.Select(e => e.Current));
        if (enumerators.Reverse().All(e => {
                bool finished = !e.MoveNext();
                if (finished)
                {
                    e.Reset();
                    e.MoveNext();
                }
                return finished;
            }))
            yield break;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var list = new[] { "1", "1,2", "3", "4", "5" }.ToList();
var perms = Permutations(list, ',').ToList();
```